# Is the unencoded equals character (=) allowed as the value of a querystring?

Tags: parsing, url, encoding, query-string, url-parsing

Lets say i have the following URL:

```
http://www.foo.com?key1=bar&key2=baz=egg
```

Between "baz" and "egg" is an equals.
Does "baz=egg" count as value for key2 or has = to be encoded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on your server configuration, so maybe its a good idea to encode it, but certainly on my server the value of key2 in the above example is 'baz=egg' and so encoding is not needed.